# Is there a politically neutral Chinese term for Greater China that is acceptable to all Chinese speakers?

Tags: topolect, taiwan, mainland-china, hong-kong

By "China," I am referring to the Mainland, Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan collectively, without regard to geopolitics. Is there a word that refers to this entire region that would not offend any Mainlanders, Taiwanese or citizens of the Special Administrative Units?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_China or in Chinese 大中華

Comment: [Singapore's 8world](https://www.8world.com/news/greater-china) uses 中港台 for Greater China, but of course that implies Taiwan/HK is separate from China in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**maybe** "大中華區". most multinational corporations used this term to describe the regions you mentioned.

such usage is correct, in context of nowadays, or recent decades. historically, taiwan was integrated into the chinese empire after ~1683. before that time, formosa was colonised by the dutch, spanish.

[history of taiwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Taiwan)

last, and most importantly is: how do you define "chinese speakers".

there're many ethnicities in "greater china" can speak chinese, they've their own cultures, languages and ideas of state / nation. so, "politically neutral" is, imo, unattainable.

it's better to seek a term that's vague, fuzzy enough; that no-one want to waste time and effort to argue its precise definition.

Comment: I mean speakers of any of the Chinese family of languages such as 国语，粤语，客家话，闽南话 who use Standard Chinese for written communication. I'm not counting Tibetans, Mongols, Uyghurs or other minorities who speak unrelated languages and have different writing systems.

Comment: Though it is the only one available, it still sounds very strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

中國大陸和台灣 / mainland China and Taiwan

Obviously Taiwan is not located inside mainland, so restricting China to mainland China may meet your purpose

Comment: No, this won't include HK and Macau. Greater China is quite internationally recognized

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "大中華區" is quite common for this issue. There are other expressions such as 兩岸三地(中、台、港) or 兩岸四地(中、台、港、澳)

"大中華區" is a bit vague to me, because it might include Chinese speakers in Singapore and Malaysia. The concept of this word varies from organization to organization.

Maybe the question is: Why do you want to describe Mainland China, Hong Kong, Macau and Taiwan collectively? What's the topic? For instance, if you want to compare Chinese-speaking music or films in this region, you can use"華語圈"(Chinese-speaking area)
it's very common to say 華語流行音樂 or 華語電影.

Comment: No, 大中华区 won’t include Chinese speakers from Singapore and Malaysia... because it’s a term for region not for people. If you want to describe people, 华人 is probably the broadest term to include all Chinese who identify them with root of Chinese, for example, 印尼华人、马来西亚华人、新加坡华人 etc. any corporation include Malaysia and Singapore in greater China region is probably just being lazy...

Comment: You didn't read the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

NO, there is no one single term that would satisfy everyone.

Just take another country we all know, which is called:-

England, Great Britain, British Isles, United Kingdom......